# Common conditional rendering pattern in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am new to react and hooks. I have four pages (functional components that uses react hooks) in which I need to render another component based on some condition.
I know I can always do conditional rendering.
Like,

Page1
return isValid ? component1 : component2;

Page2
return isValid ? component1 : component3;

Page3
return isValid ? component1 : component4;

so here component1 (which I want to render in each page if condition is true) is same for all four pages.
But it seems I need to do this for all four pages/functional components.I would not like to repeat this code for multiple components as it makes component not readable and loads with many lines of code.

I would like to know that is there any other way I can render say component1 if condition is true without writing repetitive code in all four pages?
Say using higher order component(HOC) or custom hooks or any interceptor pattern?

For example, using HOC,

```
withValidation(component2)
withValidation(component3)
withValidation(component4)
```

Here, withValidation HOC returns component1(which will be another component) if condition is true or returns wrapped component. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle the routing? Because it can be done with react-router-dom like this (names of components are just for example):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './header'
import User from './user'
import Repository from './repository'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      // <Header> is the common component, you can use conditions instead like {visible && <Header />}
      <Header /> 
      // here below we manage how components depends on url
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/:user" component={() => <User />} />
        <Route exact path="/:user/:repository" component={() => <Repository />} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
}
```

Combining conditios and routes you can create quite complex logic of what should be rendered and when exactly.